# Dart: How do I extract text from string?

Tags: dart

I have the following string from which I wish to get the text in the src tag.What would be the Regular Expression or Function I would have to use.

```
var string ='<img src=\"https://d3btgtzu3ctdwx.cloudfront.net/nf1?t=8e67f6f9-efba-4c3b-b718-517512044736\" height=\"1\" width=\"1\" border=\"0\" alt=\"\" style=\"height: 0; width: 0;\" />'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have much experience with Dart, but with Python I quickly solved this in:

```py
import re

data = "<img src=\"https://d3btgtzu3ctdwx.cloudfront.net/nf1?t=8e67f6f9-efba-4c3b-b718-517512044736\" height=\"1\" width=\"1\" border=\"0\" alt=\"\" style=\"height: 0; width: 0;\" />"

src = re.search("src=\"(.+?)\"", data).group(1)

print(src)
```

In Dart, I can possibly do (using Google Search skills):

```dart
var data = "<img src=\"https://d3btgtzu3ctdwx.cloudfront.net/nf1?t=8e67f6f9-efba-4c3b-b718-517512044736\" height=\"1\" width=\"1\" border=\"0\" alt=\"\" style=\"height: 0; width: 0;\" />";

var src = RegExp(r'src="(.+?)"').firstMatch(data)?.group(1);
```

I have not tested it yet but would be happy to rectify it.